# postgresql: numeric to timestamp issue with timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

I have extracted some emails from gmail into postgresql. the dates are stored  in numeric. some few sample dates are

```
1399586523000
1399773692000
1400191333000
1400378501000
1400796072000
1401008483000
1401400912000
1401588106000
```

when I convert them into timestamp

```
to_timestamp(date/1000) at time zone 'UTC+10' as senttimestamp
```

The Issue is that neither the timezone match nor the minutes part in the email match. I could have easily shifted the timezone forward or backward to adjust but the minute part of the date also does not match. I doubt that maybe I am incorrectly coverting from numeric to timestamp

For example, 1399586523000 timestamp should be Thu, May 8, 2014 at 4:21 PM but when I use the

```
to_timestamp(date/1000) at time zone 'UTC+10' as senttimestamp
```

None of the converted timestamp match the actual sent timestamp

Can someone please help

Arif

Answer (score 1):

> For example, 1399586523000 timestamp should be Thu, May 8, 2014 at
>   4:21 PM

Assuming an UTC timestamp in number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970, the expected result is incorrect and PostgreSQL's result is correct.

Here's what Perl's localtime gives:

```
$ LANG=C TZ=GMT 
 perl -e 'use POSIX; print strftime("%c", localtime(1399586523));'
```

result: **Thu May  8 22:02:03 2014**

```
$ LANG=C TZ=UTC+10
  perl -e 'use POSIX; print strftime("%c", localtime(1399586523));'
```

result: **Thu May  8 12:02:03 2014**

PostgreSQL:

```
=> select to_timestamp(1399586523) at time zone 'UTC+10';
      timezone       
---------------------
 2014-05-08 12:02:03
(1 row)
```

Date in mail messages are expressed in [RFC-822 format](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/), not in Unix timestamps, so it' not obvious how your timestamps were obtained and what they represent exactly.

Comment: FWIW, the X-Received header seems to store a Unix timestamp as part of an SMTP id.